# What is the swift underscore's official name?

Tags: swift, terminology

I have been trying to learn the names of the Swift features recently so that I can communicate with people with these names.

For example

- If `!` is added to the end of a type name, it's called an "implicitly unwrapped optional type"
- `guard` denotes a "guard statement"
- `if let x = someOptional` is called "Optional binding"
- `case 0...9:` is an example of "pattern matching" in switch statements

But there is one feature that I don't know the name of.

Usually, I write this kind of code because C-style for loops are deprecated:

```
for _ in 0...9 {
    print("hello") //print hello 10 times
}
```

I want to know what the underscore is called.

I know that this is from Ruby. So I think it will have the same name as the underscore in Ruby. So what exactly is the underscore called?

My guesses:

- the underscore operator
- the underscore
- the underscore literal
- the underscore identifier
- the underscore to omit stuff

Is there an official term for this? If there isn't, how would I call this in a casual conversation about my code?

Comment: I've tried getting some insights by looking at the warning you are given if you initialise a value but never use it, but there's no clue about how it's called. Just `consider replacing with assignment to '_' or remove it.`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's called a wildcard pattern:

> #### Wildcard Pattern
>
> A wildcard pattern matches and ignores any value and consists of an underscore (`_`). Use a wildcard pattern when you don’t care about the values being matched against. For example, the following code iterates through the closed range `1...3`, ignoring the current value of the range on each iteration of the loop:
>
> ```
> for _ in 1...3 {
>    // Do something three times.
> }
> ```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-ID420

Comment: Oh thank you! I did not expect it to be in the "Patterns" category! That's why I couldn't find it!